# How to get rid of the white flash when changing background image with animation?

Tags: css, html, css-animations

The code makes it so the background image of the site transitions between 5 different images but everytime a animation is done and the next animation starts there's a white flash. How do I get rid of it or what have I done wrong? I'm not sure how to explain it in any other way.

```css
@keyframes backswitch {
  0% {
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
  }
  20% {
    background-image: url("background_2.jpg");
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url("background_3.jpg");
  }
  60% {
    background-image: url("background_4.jpg");
  }
  80% {
    background-image: url("background_5.jpg");
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url("background_6.jpg");
  }
}

body {
  /*Adjusting images and animation*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  animation-name: backswitch;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/vavik96/pen/yyKoag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to preload your images:

```css
@keyframes backswitch {
  0% {background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/300/ccc/fff.png");}
  20% {background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/300/3f5/fff.png");}
  40% {background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/300/71c/fff.png");}
  60% {background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/300/228/fff.png");}
  80% {background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/300/c11/fff.png");}
  100% {background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/300/544/fff.png");}
}
body {
  /*Adjusting images and animation*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  animation-name: backswitch;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

div.preload-images {
  background: url("https://dummyimage.com/300/ccc/fff.png") no-repeat -9999px -9999px;
  background: url("https://dummyimage.com/300/ccc/fff.png") no-repeat -9999px -9999px,
    url("https://dummyimage.com/300/3f5/fff.png") no-repeat -9999px -9999px,
    url("https://dummyimage.com/300/71c/fff.png") no-repeat -9999px -9999px,
    url("https://dummyimage.com/300/228/fff.png") no-repeat -9999px -9999px,
    url("https://dummyimage.com/300/c11/fff.png") no-repeat -9999px -9999px,
    url("https://dummyimage.com/300/544/fff.png") no-repeat -9999px -9999px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="preload-images"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign background-image property to the body you can preload all of the images and this problem should disappear.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background_1.jpg"), url("background_2.jpg"), url("background_3.jpg"), url("background_4.jpg"), url("background_5.jpg"), url("background_6.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  animation-name: backswitch;
  animation-duration: 60s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  
}

@keyframes backswitch {
  0% {
    background-image: url("background.jpg");
  }
  20% {
    background-image: url("background_2.jpg");
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url("background_3.jpg");
  }
  60% {
    background-image: url("background_4.jpg");
  }
  80% {
    background-image: url("background_5.jpg");
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url("background_6.jpg");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the behaviour of standard images (as opposed to background images).
They dont seem to suffer from this issue, at least not in Firefox or Chrome.
So you could put your top layer content in a relative div with z-index 1, then put an image in an absolute div with z-index 0.
Shouldn't take long to update your css and get everything to fit nicely.